# How can I draw route on own path?

Tags: android, routes, mapbox

```
{
"type":"FeatureCollection",
"generator":"JOSM",
"features":[
    {
        "type":"Feature",
        "properties":{
        },
        "geometry":{
            "type":"LineString",
            "coordinates":[
                [
                    121.54821846780,
                    24.98741107673
                ],
                [
                    121.54812039953,
                    24.98739360280
                ],
                [
                    121.54812750162,
                    24.98736155308
                ],
                [
                    121.54813477853,
                    24.98732871440
                ],
                [
                    121.54814403650,
                    24.98728693577
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type":"Feature",
        "properties":{
        },
        "geometry":{
            "type":"LineString",
            "coordinates":[
                [
                    121.54813477853,
                    24.98732871440
                ],
                [
                    121.54819734540,
                    24.98733966151
                ],
                [
                    121.54819365737,
                    24.98735561598
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type":"Feature",
        "properties":{
        },
        "geometry":{
            "type":"LineString",
            "coordinates":[
                [
                    121.54812750162,
                    24.98736155308
                ],
                [
                    121.54780189872,
                    24.98730374867
                ],
                [
                    121.54776282754,
                    24.98729681235
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

this is Geojson path,how could I draw two point,and the route will follow this path?
I used JOSM to draw.

```
 if (route == true) {
                        start = mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(point.getLatitude(), point.getLongitude())).title("start").icon(icon));
                        route = false;
                    } else {
                        if(destination!=null){
                            mapboxMap.removeMarker(destination);
                        }
                        destination = mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(point.getLatitude(), point.getLongitude())).title("finish"));

                        LatLng[] points = new LatLng[2];
                        LatLng loc = new LatLng(start.getPosition());
                        LatLng dest = new LatLng(destination.getPosition());
                        points[0] = loc;
                        points[1] = dest;
                        if (poly != null) {
                            mapboxMap.removePolyline(poly);
                        }
                        poly = mapboxMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                                .add(points)
                                .color(Color.parseColor("#3887be"))
                                .width(5));

                    }
```

the route is straight line,I want route draw on my Geojson path,how can i do?
I want the two marker follow my path to plan the best path,I can load the Geojson path on Android and draw the path on map,but how do i let the two point follow my path to creat the route? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for making a route along your path:

```
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(
    new LatLng(Longitude,Latitude),
    new LatLng(Longitude,Latitude), // add many as you want
    )
         .width(10)
         .color(Color.Red)
    );
```

For two random points on map, try the answer given here 
[Get location of clicked point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302112/how-to-get-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-location-where-user-taps-on-the-map-in)
 
 This is an example of single marker(Source) but you can store these values in temp variables and can get another marker(Dest.).
 After getting both the points, you can create a path between them using Polyline.

Comment: Thank you! But When I manually click on the random starting point and end point, how to make the path drawn on my path?

Comment: Editing my answer...Edited

Answer (score 0):

First check you got proper GeoJson. Then for draw direction use below method.
If you found proper then get waypoint array from response by using this code:

```
List<DirectionsRoute> route = response.body().getRoutes().get(0).getGeometry().getWaypoints();
```

Pass this waypoint array to below method. It will use AsyncTask for draw a polyline.

```
public void drawDirection(List<DirectionsRoute> route) {
        map.clear();
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Destination")
                .snippet("Distance: "+String.valueOf(route.get(0).getDistance()/1000))
                .position(destLatlng));
        new DrawGeoJson().execute(route);
    }
```

Below is AsyncTask for draw polyline with multiple route (if possible) with multiple color.

```
private class DrawGeoJson extends AsyncTask<List<DirectionsRoute>,String,List<List<LatLng>>>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected List<List<LatLng>> doInBackground(List<DirectionsRoute>... params) {

            List<List<LatLng>> pointsArray =new ArrayList<>();
            List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
            String jsonResponse= getString(R.string.jsonResponse);
            String ch=jsonResponse.substring(95,110);
            Log.d("Char",String.valueOf(ch));

            try {
                List<DirectionsRoute> routeList=params[0];
              //If more than one route available then this loop will iterate for every route.
                for(int i=0;i<routeList.size();i++) {
                    points=new ArrayList<>();
                    DirectionsRoute route = params[0].get(i);
                    for (List<Double> doubleList : route.getGeometry().getCoordinates()) {
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(doubleList.get(1), doubleList.get(0));
                        points.add(latLng);
                    }
                    pointsArray.add(points);
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                Log.e("LOG", "Exception Loading GeoJSON: " + exception.toString());
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return pointsArray;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<LatLng>> pointsArray) {
            super.onPostExecute(pointsArray);
            if(pointsArray.size()>0) {
                int[] rainbow=MainActivity.this.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.rainbow);
                for(int i=0;i<pointsArray.size();i++) {
                    int colorForPolyline;
                    if(i>rainbow.length){
                        colorForPolyline=i%7;
                    }else{
                        colorForPolyline=i;
                    }
                    if (pointsArray.get(i).size() > 0) {
                        map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                                .addAll(pointsArray.get(i))
                                .color(rainbow[colorForPolyline])
                                .width(4));
                    }
                }
            }

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(sourceLatlng) // Sets the center of the map to Maracanã
                    .bearing(0) // Sets the orientation of the camera to look west
                    .tilt(20) // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build(); // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), 3000, null);
        }
    }
```